# HTML From Array not POSTing in MS Edge Randomly

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a HTML form with some PHP that for the most part does not POST the data in the form when used in MS Edge or Internet Explorer. Works fine in Google Chrome. I have read of similar issues and suggested fixes for them were to adjust settings on the server with PHP, these had to effect for me.

I have also just noticed that a 'PHP Stack Trace:,' is logged in the Apache Error Log. But this happens in Edge and Chrome.

Here is my form...

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

 <html lang="en">
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['homegroup'])){
$HOMEGROUP = $_POST['homegroup'];
 }
 include "connection.php"; //Connect to Database
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>
<form name="data" method="post" action="record.php">
    <table border="1" align="center" class="title">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7">

            <?php
            echo $HOMEGROUP;
            ?>

        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" align="center" class="title2">
            <p>Please enter uniform infringement details in the text boxes bellow. Leave blank if no infringement.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT `registration`, `FIRST_NAME`, `SURNAME`, `GENDER`, `SCHOOL_YEAR`, `ROLL_GROUP`, `HOUSE` FROM `students` WHERE `ROLL_GROUP`='$HOMEGROUP' AND STATUS = 'FULL' or 'PART' ORDER BY `SURNAME` ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //echo $row["FIRST_NAME"]. " " . $row["SURNAME"]. " " . $row["GENDER"]. " " . $row["SCHOOL_YEAR"]. " " . $row["ROLL_GROUP"]. " " . $row["HOUSE"]. "<br>";  -OLD


                    echo '<tr class="datarow">';

                    echo '<td align="center">';
                    echo '<a href="photos17\\'.$row['SURNAME'].", ".$row['FIRST_NAME'].'.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="photos17\\'.$row['SURNAME'].", ".$row['FIRST_NAME'].'.jpg" height="60"></a>';
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="combname">
                            <input class="combname" style="border:none" readonly="" type="text" size="25" name="comb_name[]" value=" ' . $row['FIRST_NAME']. " " . $row['SURNAME'].' ">
                            <input style="border:none" readonly="" type="hidden" name="first_name[]" value="'.$row['FIRST_NAME'].'">
                            <input style="border:none" readonly="" type="hidden" name="surname[]" value="'.$row['SURNAME'].'">
                            <input style="border:none" readonly="" type="hidden" name="registration[]" value="'.$row['registration'].'">
                    </td>';

                    echo '<td class="items">
                            Hat:<select name="hat[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select><br>Jewellery:<select name="jewellery[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>';

                    echo '<td class="items">
                            Socks:<select name="socks[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select><br>Make Up:<select name="makeup[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>';

                    echo '<td class="items">
                            Hair:<select name="hair[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select><br>Shoes:<select name="shoes[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>';

                    echo '<td class="items">
                            Incorrect Uniform:<select name="icuniform[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select><br>Incorrect PE Uniform:<select name="icpeuniform[]">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1">Y</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>';

                    echo '<td class="items">Other: <br>
                            <input type="text" size="15" id="infringement" name="infringement[]" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="gender[]" value="'.$row['GENDER'].'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="year[]" value="'.$row['SCHOOL_YEAR'].'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="rollgroup[]" value="'.$row['ROLL_GROUP'].'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="house[]" value="'.$row['HOUSE'].'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="user[]" value="$user"></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';



                }



            } else {

                header("location: nostudents.php");

            }
            ?>

            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
            <input type="button" onclick="location.href='search.php';" name="back" value="Back">
            </td>
            <td colspan="5" align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Infringements">
            </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When completing all I get is an empty 'Array ()' sent to my record.php and thus nothing is saved in my database. Seems to fail most times when submitting. It seems to be completely random and nothing shows up in any logs I can find.

Record.php

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />


 <?php

 //session_start();

 include "connection.php"; //Connect to Database

 //Un-comment bellow to view entire array from previous form.
'<pre>'.print_r($_POST).'</pre>';
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<br>";

 if (!empty($_POST) ){


foreach(($_POST['registration']) as $key=>$row)
    {   
        $registration        = $row;
    if (!empty($_POST['infringement'][$key]) ){ 
        $infringement = $_POST['infringement'][$key];
    } else {
        $infringement = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['surname'][$key]) ){  
        $surname = $_POST['surname'][$key];
    } else {
        $surname = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['first_name'][$key]) ){   
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'][$key];
    } else {
        $first_name = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['gender'][$key]) ){   
        $gender = $_POST['gender'][$key];
    } else {
        $gender = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['year'][$key]) ){ 
        $year = $_POST['year'][$key];
    } else {
        $year = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['rollgroup'][$key]) ){    
        $rollgroup = $_POST['rollgroup'][$key];
    } else {
        $rollgroup = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['house'][$key]) ){    
        $house = $_POST['house'][$key];
    } else {
        $house = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['user'][$key]) ){ 
        $user = $_POST['user'][$key];
    } else {
        $user = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['hat'][$key]) ){  
        $hat = $_POST['hat'][$key];
    } else{
        $hat = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['jewellery'][$key]) ){    
        $jewellery = $_POST['jewellery'][$key];
    } else { 
        $jewellery = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['socks'][$key]) ){    
        $socks = $_POST['socks'][$key];
    } else {
        $socks = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['makeup'][$key]) ){   
        $makeup = $_POST['makeup'][$key];
    } else {
        $makeup = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['hair'][$key]) ){ 
        $hair = $_POST['hair'][$key];
    } else {
        $hair = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['shoes'][$key]) ){    
        $shoes = $_POST['shoes'][$key];
    } else {
        $shoes = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['icuniform'][$key]) ){    
        $icuniform = $_POST['icuniform'][$key];
    } else {
        $icuniform = '';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['icpeuniform'][$key]) ){  
        $icpeuniform = $_POST['icpeuniform'][$key];
    } else {
        $icpeuniform = '';
    }
    $date = "NOW()";        

    $first_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$first_name);

    $surname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$surname);


    //echo $key;
    //echo $row;
    //echo $hat;

if(!empty($infringement) OR !empty($hat) OR !empty($jewellery) OR !empty($socks) OR !empty($makeup) OR !empty($hair) OR !empty($shoes) OR !empty($icuniform) OR !empty($icpeuniform) OR !empty($infringement))
{   
$sql = "INSERT INTO infringements
(id, registration, first_name, surname, infringement, gender, school_year, roll_group, house, hat, jewellery, socks, makeup, hair, shoes, icuniform, icpeuniform, user, submittime)
VALUES (null,'{$registration}','{$first_name}','{$surname}','{$infringement}','{$gender}','{$year}','{$rollgroup}','{$house}','{$hat}','{$jewellery}','{$socks}','{$makeup}','{$hair}','{$shoes}','{$icuniform}','{$icpeuniform}','{$user}',{$date})";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));      

//Un-commend bellow to view SQL input query.        
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br>";
}       

}

header("location: record.php");



unset($_POST);  

 }
?>






<table align='center'>
<tr>
<td class='title2'>
<br>
<h1>Uniform Infringement:</h1>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align='center'>
<p> Thank you, your Uniform Infringements have been recorded.</p>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">
<br>
<br>

</td>
```

Comment: whats in record.php?

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't work. The next step would be to use F12 to bring up the Edge developer tools. Check the DOM Explorer to make sure it is correct. Maybe you have a misplaced tag somewhere that is causing Edge to prematurely end the form. If the HTML structure looks good, post the form and use the Network tab to see if Edge is actually sending any POST data.

Comment: When I load the DOM Explorer on that page it come up blank, which seems odd. Looking at the Network tab, there is a POST every time the form is submitted, regardless if the array has data or just 'Array()'

Comment: I have gone over it very closely again. Compared the html output from Edge to Chrome and they both display exactly the same, plus a minor added extra space at the beginning. Its very frustrating.

Comment: We'll i'm stuck. Any other suggestions?